SSL not recognized on WebSocket c# server
I'm trying to connect to my C# (net6.0) TCP server application using JS WebSocket. it works as an insecure but now I'm trying to switch to secure WebSocket.
I have a self-sign SSL that I have added to the MMC. (it was added in Local Computer certificate snap-in)
I'm using Windows 11. I have tried to run it as an admin.
Here is the server application log. X509Certificate2 verifies that it is valid. Yet the sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer throws an error.
Private key exists: Yes
Certificate valid: Yes

Server has started on 127.0.0.1:20000, Waiting for a connection…
Client 1 has connected.
Exception: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
Inner exception: The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
Client 1 has disconnected.

My SSL is made in bash like this
KEY_SIZE=2048
PRIVATE_KEY_FILE='myserver.key'
CERTIFICATE_FILE='myserver.crt'
PFX_FILE='myserver.pfx'
KEY_PASSWORD='my_password'
PFX_PASSWORD='my_password'
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:$KEY_PASSWORD -out $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE $KEY_SIZE
openssl req -new -key $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE -out request.csr -passin pass:$KEY_PASSWORD
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in request.csr -signkey $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE -out $CERTIFICATE_FILE -passin pass:$KEY_PASSWORD
openssl pkcs12 -export -out $PFX_FILE -inkey $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE -in $CERTIFICATE_FILE -passin pass:$KEY_PASSWORD -password pass:$PFX_PASSWORD
rm request.csr

I set up my certificate on my server application like this:
X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("myserver.pfx", "my_password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
Console.WriteLine("Private key exists: " + (ServerCertificate.HasPrivateKey ? "Yes" : "No"));
Console.WriteLine("Certificate valid: " + (ServerCertificate.Verify() ? "Yes" : "No"));

I handle connections here. This is also where I get the error.
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.Stream);
try {
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(ServerCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
    // Proceed with the WebSocket handshake...
}
catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}");
    if (e.InnerException != null) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inner exception: {e.InnerException.Message}");
    }
    client.Disconnect();
    continue;
}

My html js client looks like this:
const websocket = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:20000");

websocket.onopen = (e) => {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
};

websocket.onclose = (e) => {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
};

websocket.onmessage = (e) => {
    writeToScreen(`<span>${e.data}</span>`);
};

websocket.onerror = (e) => {
    writeToScreen(`<span class="error">ERROR:</span> ${e.data}`);
};

Note that I run the server application and client on the same machine (as you can see from the IP)
and that both client and server run on Windows.

"I have a self-sign SSL that I have added to the MMC." doesn't square with the code new X509Certificate2("myserver.pfx", where you pull it from a file. Which is it? If it's in the machine store, does the current user have permissions on the private key? Also kind of weird to generate the CSR on the same server that signs it, normally it would be the machine requesting that would generate it.

what are you talking about? I Add the CRT I generate to MMC (Local Computer). If I didn't, the PFX would not be valid. I also run the client and server on the same computer here. How would the JS client be able to generate a CSR?

I'm saying that the code new X509Certificate2("myserver.pfx", indicates you are loading it from a file, not from the machine store (accessed via MMC). So why would MMC be relevant? What does the JS client have to do with that, it doesn't seem to be providing its own client certificate?

without MMC, my myserver.pfx would not be valid.

Not sure why you think that, it's perfectly reasonable to load an X509Certificate2 directly from a file, and completely separate to loading it from the machine store. Either way, this is a self-signed certificate, are you sure the browser/JS is going to trust that?

The client don't complain. If I don't ad the crt to MMC, ServerCertificate.Verify() returns false.

Because the certificate isn't valid. It's not issued by a trusted provider. Self-signed certificates aren't trusted by definition. Someone will have to add them manually to the list of trusted certificates. On your machine you did so yourself  using MMC but you could also do it using the dotnet dev-certs command. That doesn't make it trusted for any other machine. The only reason HTTPS works during development in .NET Core programs is they use the self-signed certificate created and installed by dotnet dev-certs on the development machine.

new SslStream isn't Web Sockets with HTTPS either. What is your actual server-side implementation? ASP.NET Core already supports WebSockets with HTTPS out of the box. HTTP/2 requires HTTPS. HTTPS is handled by the ASP.NET Core middleware itself. The WebSockets middleware runs after the HTTPS middleware

I use a TcpListener. The Websocket works without issue. it is only the way that I'm having issues with. When using crt from dotnet dev-certs and replacing 127.0.0.1 with localhost, it works!
